# How were self employed folk taxed in the U.K. before 1997

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom

From 1997 onwards, self employed folk in the U.K.  submit self assessment returns to HMRC.

But how was it done before 1997?

Comment: Do you (or does anyone you know) owe taxes on self-employment income from before 1997?

Comment: @NathanL classy ;-) actually, I'm genuinely intrigued. I've spent an entire train journey from London to Exeter Googling this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This link:  http://www.ifs.org.uk/fs/articles/ewgm_feb93.pdf (from 1996, describing the proposals for the change) seems to answer the question in its description of "the current system" - they had to file business accounts and it was calculated by the Inland Revenue from that.

Comment: Thanks for this. That's an excellent find! Have an upvote while I can - I lost the privilege when I spent all my points on the bounty, and if someone downvotes my question I'm back once more in the doldrums.

Comment: @Bathsheba you can also award the bounty early if it suits you. This is a very good answer.